# Aparece el mensaje de error "Display Name must be no more than 30 characters", en inglés

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, perfil

En la página de perfil, zona de configuración, me sale este error en inglés:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es:

> Display Name must be no more than 30 characters

Comment: Don't worry about language :). You are refering to the `Display Name must be..`? It's extrange, i looked it up and it seems to be translated ( https://traducir.win/string/8516 ).Let's wait for @g3rv4 to explore it more in detail.

Comment: @Pikoh hm, are you using traducir for translation, not transifex?

Comment: Yes. Traducir.win is a wrapper around transifex made by @g3rv4 that we use here in [es.so]

Comment: Traducir.win  makes it a lot easier to maintain the localization. You can check the project here: https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir

Comment: @Pikoh thanks! I'll check it)

Comment: checking it out :)

Comment: Porque hablan todos en ingles? si estamos en nuestra meta :p

Comment: @gbianchi porque el OP no habla español :) e hizo la pregunta en inglés

Comment: @Suvitruf I translated your post into Spanish. I don't know if I should keep the English version... in any case, thanks for reporting this!

Comment: @fedorqui thanks. Glad to help (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gracias por reportar esto! es un bug en el código. Ya lo reporté al equipo de Q&A y está corregido en el sitio.

---

Thanks for your report! this is a bug on our code... I've flagged it and the Q&A team already shipped a fix.